# C++/CLI, NUnit and Resharper

Tags: nunit, c++-cli, resharper

Say I have an NUnit test project written in C++/CLI, built with the `/clr` switch. That is, it can reference and use native code, it's not a pure managed assembly.

NUnit can run projects like these, but can this be done from Visual Studio using Resharper? I have `R#` 5.x, and I can't (can't even see the `R#` icons by the left edge of the code window to launch the tests). Can the latest version of `R#` do this?

Comment: If you want R# like features for C++ give [Visual Assist X](http://www.wholetomato.com/) a try

Comment: I'm not so interested in refactoring capabilities as much as I am in running unit tests from inside Visual Studio. Can Visual Assist X do that?

Comment: Nevermind, I just confirmed that `R#` can do it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ReSharper doesn't support C++/CLI, and thus it doesn't show Test icons in the source file. However, it should show tests from output assemblies in Unit Test Explorer (see ReSharper / Windows) and you should be able to right-click project and use Run Tests from context menu.